# INTERFACE AND INHERITANCE. (Error states the methods are not abstract. How do i rectify that?)

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, interface, extends

> Write a program to create an interface where you have to declare a variable `int x= 20` and create an abstract class. Inside that class again declare variable `int x=10`. Create a new class named `test` that inherit abstract class and interface. Inside that class create a method print and print all the values of x.

```
interface A
{
    int x = 20;
    void abc(); 
}
abstract class C implements A
{
    void def();
    {
        int x = 10;
    }
}
class test extends C
{
    static void print()
    {
        test obj = new test();
        obj.abc();
        System.out.println(x);
        test obj1 = new test();
        obj.def();
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    public static void main(String arg[])
}
```

Comment: remove the `;` at the end of `void def();`

Comment: Why do you have the methods `abc` and `def`? They don't seem to be part of the requirements of the exercise and are merely complicating your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely understand the question, but here we go:

First you want to declare an interface `A` with a variable `x` whose default value is `20`

```
interface A {
    int x = 20;
}
```

Then an abstract class `C` that implements `A` and overrides the value of `x` to set it to `10`

```
abstract class C implements A {
    int x = 10;
}
```

Then this is not very clear in your requirement but I think the best way to show what you want to show is to have 2 classes, one implementing `A` and one extending `C`. both of which have a `print()` method that display their value of `x`. Let's call them `TestA` and `TestC` respectively

```
class TestA implements A {

    void print() {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

}
```

```
class TestC extends C {

    void print() {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

}
```

Now, you can have a class `Test` that instantiate a `TestA` and a `TestC` and call their `print()` methods.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestA().print();
        new TestC().print();
    }
}
```

So now when you run `Test`, it outputs:

```
20
10
```

So what that means is that in a class implementing `A`, the value of `x` is `20` by default (as in `TestA`). But you can override that value and change it to anything you want (as in `TestC`).

Comment: I think the `def()` method may have been intended to be an abstract method. In either case, the OP's problem is that they do not declare a class-level `x` but rather a local variable, so it cannot be printed. I'd say the original instructions of the exercise are very unclear.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes true, will rewrite my answer